# With the mainForm demo ,I can't receive any verification code on telegram

Tags: wtelegramclient

WTelegramClient/Examples/WinForms_app/WTelegramClientTestWF/MainForm

After pressing the button "Connect/Login",

The interface is displayed as follows:

Connecting & login into Telegram servers...
A verification code is required...

the verification code cannot be received.

How to solve it? thanks

I'm in China, could that example not work? Is there another way to log in?